# Android animation memory error (OutOfMemeory)

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a layout with 2 buttons that each activates animation. On button click the layout with buttons disappearing and the animation starts. It works except one problem, I can`t activate the second animation after the first because memory problem. After one of the animations is played i have to somehow free memory so the second animation could load. How can I free the animation and delete all frames?

Here is my code:

```
public class BermadMain extends Activity {
public static final String TAG = "Bermad";

AnimationDrawable animation, animation2, animation3;
ImageView imageAnim;
RelativeLayout lay;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rallay);


  imageAnim =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    final Button refinery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.refinery);
    refinery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i=85;
            animation = new AnimationDrawable();
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref1), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref2), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref3), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref4), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref5), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref6), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref7), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref8), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref9), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref10), i);
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref11), i); 
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref12), i); 
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ref13), i);

            imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
            imageAnim.post(new Refiney());
            lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        }
    });

    final Button oil = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oil);
    oil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i=85;
            animation2 = new AnimationDrawable();
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil1), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil2), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil3), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil4), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil5), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil6), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil7), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil8), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil9), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil10), i);
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil11), i); 
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil12), i); 
            animation2.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.oil13), i); 

            imageAnim.setBackgroundDrawable(animation2);
            imageAnim.post(new Oil());
            lay.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });


}

public void onBackPressed() {

    lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    return;
}   

class Refiney implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        animation.start();        
    }
}

class Oil implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        animation2.start();        
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add largeHeap=true in your application tag of your manifest to know if it's only a memory problem.

Comment: I am sure that this is memory problem. First of all i get an error that says "OutOfMemory" and already dealt with this problem when tried to activate only one animation, I just resized the images and it worked fine for one animation. But if future i will need more animations than 2. And I cant load all of them in the memory. So after playing each animation I have to dump the memory.

Comment: so try to affect your old AnimationDrawable to null and call System.gc()

Comment: Good idea! The thing is the System.gc() is only indication to the VM that it would be a good time to run the garbage collector. There is no guarantee that the garbage collector will actually be run.
Tried that, did`t worked.
Although adding "largeHeap=true" working just fine with 3 animation, but when added another one it still crashes.

Comment: Try to do your AnimationDrawable in XML because here you decode a lot of drawable but you free nothing, if you do that in XML, it can be solve the problem.

Comment: I suggest to avoid the largeHeap=true approach because it's probably just delaying a problem which will sooner or later happen.

You can try to use tools like LeakCanary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to inspect the memory leak and figure out how to solve them :

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try free your drawable loaded in animation.  Check the unbindDrawables() method mentioned by Romain Guy's post. 
http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/ (the code is not in the same git but you can google it other place). Then you can do System.gc() to reclaim memory.

I am not sure whether R.drawable.xxxx is preloaded in Android. If it is, then you shall not put the pictures in drawable but in resource, and dynamically load the bitmaps.

Animation itself is memory intense action. I have an animation causing a >3M byte array allocation in my app. Although the memory is reclaimed as soon as the animation finishes, it increases my peak memory usage and sometime leads to OutOfMemory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the AnimationDrawable is it will load all images to animationdrawable Object which became heavy while there where more than 12MB images. If you put `largeHeap=true` it will adjust HeapSize and increase Heap that help to load more than 12MB but it will OutOfmemory  while you have more bitmaps to load. For that scenario is

Use `Handler` and `runnable` for displaying image sequence one by one. That will load one by one image frame and not taking much memory.

Put your images file name with incremental number sequence and use below code for display it.

```
int i=0;
Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                displayBitmap(i);
                i++;
                imageView.postDelayed(r, 0);
            }
        };

    private void displayBitmap(int id) {
        String filePath ="FullpathofFileName"+.jpg";
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        if (b != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }

    }
```